# Azure databricks notebook call from azure data factory based on if/else flag

Tags: azure, if-statement, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

.[image]

I am exec adb notebook in if/else condition from adf

I have a lookup which will check flag condition in delta lake table
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM db.check where job_status = 2 and site ='xxx-xxx-xxx'. This will give me a count 2 and I used it in the if part condition @equals(activity('select job status').output.value[0],2) it should call adb notebook else logic app.

Issue After lookup pipline is not going inside if part?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I found solution mistake in output.value[0].cnt,'2' it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @anuj for your solution. Posting it as an answer to help other community members.

To refer to `lookup` activity value of a column in later activities, include the column name in the expression as below.

```
@equals(activity('select job status').output.value[0].cnt,2)
```